# How to return function with img.onload?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, filereader, onload

I am currently building an application, in which a user can upload several images and work with them simultaneously. Since some processes performed poorly due to large image files, I want to resize them, before the user gets them.

In my `resizer()` function I try to resize using canvas. It works, but since the 'canvas.toDataURL()' is inside the `img.onload` function, I don't know how to return the value and parse it to the `handleFiles()` function.

Also...I tried some cases in which I got some code from the `handleFiles()` - like:

```
var preview = document.getElementById("img"+count);
var surface = document.getElementById("cubface"+count);
var count = counterImg();
preview.src =  resizer(e.target.result, count);
surface.src = resizer(e.target.result, count);
```

And put them in the end of the `img.onload` function like

```
var preview = document.getElementById("img"+number);
var surface = document.getElementById("cubface"+number);
preview.src = canvas.toDataURL;
surface.src = canvas.toDataURL;
```

I got the resize, but I got only the last image from the loop to be processed.

So the questions are:

1. In the `resizer()` function, how to return the `canvas.toDataURL` value which is in `img.onload`?
2. Why does the loop cover only the last instance and not every image and how to solve that?

Full code:

***JavaScript:***

```
function resizer(base64, number){

    // Max size for thumbnail
    if(typeof(maxWidth) === 'undefined')  maxWidth = 1200;
    if(typeof(maxHeight) === 'undefined')  maxHeight = 1200;

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = base64;

    // Create and initialize two canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasCopy = document.createElement("canvas");
    var copyContext = canvasCopy.getContext("2d");

    img.onload = function() {

        // Determine new ratio based on max size
        var ratio = 1;
        if (img.width > maxWidth)
            ratio = maxWidth / img.width;
        else if (img.height > maxHeight)
            ratio = maxHeight / img.height;

        // Draw original image in second canvas
        canvasCopy.width = img.width;
        canvasCopy.height = img.height;
        copyContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // Copy and resize second canvas to first canvas
        canvas.width = img.width * ratio;
        canvas.height = img.height * ratio;
        ctx.drawImage(canvasCopy, 0, 0, canvasCopy.width, canvasCopy.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        return canvas.toDataURL();

    };

    return img.onload;

}


function handleFiles(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var count = counterImg();
        var preview = document.getElementById("img"+count);
        var surface = document.getElementById("cubface"+count);

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload =  (function (preview, surface) {
            return function (e) {
                var newimage = resizer(e.target.result, count);
                preview.src =  newimage;
                surface.src = newimage;
                $('#image-cropper'+count).cropit('imageSrc', e.target.result);
            }
        })(preview, surface);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that in $('#image-cropper'+count) the variable count is scoped properly? You might want to add it to your function (preview, surface).

Comment: it is just this function:

`var j=0;
function counterImg() {
    j++;
    return j;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable count is not scoped properly.

There's a delay between the time you declare the function and the time you use it, therefore, each execution ends up with the same value. So the jquery selector will always return the same element. Which explains why only the last image is modified.

Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrate the execution.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lc6bngv5/1/

To fix this, simply pass count to the function that encapsulate your preview and surface :

```
    reader.onload =  (function (preview, surface, count) {
        return function (e) {
            var newimage = resizer(e.target.result, count);
            preview.src =  newimage;
            surface.src = newimage;
            $('#image-cropper'+count).cropit('imageSrc', e.target.result);
        }
    })(preview, surface, count);
```

For the second question :

The resize function returns a function. It does not return the result of that function. To get the url properly, I would use a callback function :

```
reader.onload =  (function (preview, surface, count) {
    return function (e) {
        var newimage = resizer(e.target.result, count, function(url){
            preview.src =  url;
            surface.src = url;
            $('#image-cropper'+count).cropit('imageSrc', e.target.result);
        });
    }
})(preview, surface, count);
```

And you would have to do the following changes in resize :

```
function resizer(base64, number, cb){
    ...
    img.onload = function() {
        ...
        // return canvas.toDataURL();
        cb(canvas.toDataURL());
    };
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your advice! This solved the 2nd question. Any idea how to make the return in `img.onload`, so I can parse `canvas.toDataURL();` to `handeFiles()`?

Comment: I added an edit, you could use a callback function, that would allow you to get the result properly.

Comment: Thank You! That was awesome!